# When should I use QThread::HighestPriority

Tags: c++, qt, qthread, thread-priority

1. What are the benefits and harm of using **HighestPriority** in a **QThread** (`QThread::HighestPriority`)?
2. This could harm some other operation?
3. When should I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. By using **HighestPriority** in your QT application you are giving that particular thread priority over all other threads within your application. This can be useful if you have multiple threads and want to make sure that your background threads do not steal CPU from your main thread. Harm? Not much harm can be done unless it's mis-used by human error.
2. There's not much harm that can be done unless your application hogs cpu which usually results from a bug or poorly designed code.
3. Use it when your application needs to do multiple things at once but you want to make sure, for example, that the main window stays responsive. Obviously to do so you just assign the main window **HighestPriority**.

Comment: Thanks a lot @DanK. Actually, I just have 2 threads (the main window thread and another thread created), this another thread must do some heavy calculations. Should I use **HighestPriority** in this case, or it is not necessary? What is your opinion?

Comment: Asking for high priority for computation threads is almost always a bad idea. You want to give *low* priority to those threads, so to keep the GUI thread responsive; the lost CPU time should be negligible anyway, since in a proper GUI application the main thread is idle waiting for user input (or timers) 99% of time.

Comment: You're welcome Kelvin Salton! It boils down to which thread you want to prioritize. If CPU is limited (which sometimes can be if something else on the system is hogging it) then the QT thread that is assigned HighestPriority will be more responsive.

Answer (score 2):

1. The scheduler will give more priority to that thread compared to the others at lower priority. If you ask for highest priority to a thread that never yields (e.g. a thread that does "heavy" computations without ever doing blocking syscalls) your lower priority threads may be left to starve for CPU time.

   A typical example is a worker thread at high priority competing for the CPU with the GUI thread - your GUI will likely be unresponsive most of the time.

   Of course the details will depend from the exact workings of the scheduler of the OS your application is running on. On Windows I had bad experiences even with a worker thread competing with the GUI thread at the same priority level. Recent Linux kernels feel way better in this respect.
2. On most OSes the thread priority is somehow combined with the process priority, so it shouldn't damage much other processes.
3. Personally, I've never had to use it.

   As I wrote in a comment, usually the arrangement is the opposite - you give *low* priority to background, CPU-hogging tasks; the speed difference is normally negligible (usually the GUI thread and other background thread are idling most of the time, waiting for events or polling periodically), but you keep them responsive when they need to be.

   A possible use for a high priority thread can be for soft-realtime stuff, where your thread *needs* to be scheduled every so often, preempting lower priority threads, do its thing quickly and yield back the CPU to the scheduler.

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that if you're raising a priority of any thread other than the main thread, you state that the work that thread is doing is more important than the work needed to keep the user interface responsive. Your UI will gladly get pre-empted by the highest priority thread.

Very high priority threads should be used when the latency of response is important. They should do the minimum amount of work necessary. High thread priority in that case means that as soon as the thread is runnable, it is **worth it** to burn through the CPU cycles needed to do a context switch. It better be worth it, then. Usually you'd use a high priority thread for audio or machine communications - but beware that on e.g. Linux parts of the device driver itself or the layers above it may run in a lower priority thread anyway!